# Netbook wifi switch not working on a Toshiba NB255-N245

Tags: 11.04, wireless

I recently bought a Toshiba NB255-N245 and installed 11.04 with Wubi. It's working great, except that the Fn+F8 key, which should toggle the wifi on and off, does not have any effect in Ubuntu. It works fine in Windows 7. I'd like to be able to switch off sometimes to save battery, etc. Any ideas how to make it work? I tried `rfkill block`, but the wifi light on the indicator panel stays on. Or if it's been turned off on the Windows side, `rfkill unblock` won't turn it on.

EDIT:

As I said in a comment, `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` brings the wifi down temporarily, but then it comes back up after a few seconds.

I booted up again after having disabled wifi via Fn+F8 on the Windows side. Ubuntu boots up with the indicator light off. I tried `rfkill unblock wifi` and `rfkill unblock all` with no effect or message. `ifconfig -a` does show wlan0, but `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` gives an error message:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

This machine has an Atheros chipset, BTW. `lspci` reports:

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

I noticed that the network panel applet reports "wireless is disabled by hardware switch".

EDIT 2:

I found a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/764524

Comment: you can force the interface to go down using `ifconfig` and `sudo`.  Can you do me a favor and attach the output of `ifconfig -a` to your question?

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: Unfortunately, I'm using it in Windows right now for work. I'll see if I can boot over to Ubuntu in an hour or so.

Comment: Okay, when we have the output i can post an answer saying "You can force the interface to go down using this command: <blah>" which will include the specific command to use for your setup.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: I think the interface is `wlan0`, if that's what you're getting at. I can't remember if I tried that, but I suspect that won't do any more than `rfkill` did.

Comment: it'll actually force down the interface, its worked on systems where the wifi switch doesn't work (on systems I own).  try `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` and see what happens

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: It appears to have the same effect as `rfkill block wifi`. The wifi goes down, but the indicator light stays on. Actually, it doesn't seem to STAY down. It comes back after several seconds. At least with `rfkill` it stays down.

Comment: This issue is not Toshiba-specific, the same thing happens on my Packard Bell laptop, which also has an Atheros wifi chipset. Then it's likely related to the support of Atheros chipsets in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before and what worked for me was using a live cd of fedora and booting and then in terminal do rfkill unblock all. if it says hardware block press the fn f8 combination. then do the rfkill unblock all command again. i am pretty sure the problem has to do more with bios and mbr.

if that does not work in ubuntu do:

```
sudo rmmod ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo dhclient
```

not working? let me know. i have the same card as you and have had the exact same problems.